# What is the correct way to move between pages like that?

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, when the page is load I have a header div, home div and bottoom div. I have sidebar and If I click "about" for example it refer me to "#about" (this is a div).

I want that the "home" div will hide or something else, and instead of the "home" div, ill see the about div. 
And of course to hide the about div when the page is in the home page (because when the page is load I want to see the home div).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your example code? We can't really help if you don't provide code that you have tried.

Comment: Okay, let me create example in jsfilde, ill edit it soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should be doing is creating some connection between your links and the content to be displayed(div's). You may keep the id of each content div's in HTML 5 data attributes on each of the links.

Here i am going to keep the id of the corresponding content div in a data attribute called `target`

```
<div>Header</div>

<a href="#" class="links" data-target="home">Home</a>
<a href="#" class="links" data-target="about">About</a>
<a href="#" class="links" data-target="contact">Contact</a>

<div id="home" class="content" style="display:none;">Home content</div>
<div id="about" class="content" style="display:none;">Abount content</div>
<div id="contact" class="content" style="display:none;">Contact content</div>

<div>Footer</div>
```

And when the links are clicked, get the target data attribute value and use that to get the content div and show it.

```
$(function(){

   $(".content").first().show();  //show the first div(Home content)

   $(".links").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".content").hide();
     var target=$(this).data("target");
     $("#"+target).show();

   });

})
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/japeyiv/4/edit?html,css,js,output) is a working sample.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Sorry bother you again, but when I tried it on my site, it shows me both divs when I entering my web... Maybe I miss something? @Shyju

Comment: You might have a script error in the page. Check the browser console.